# How do I tell VNC which of the two IP addresses to use?

Tags: vnc

I have a Raspberry Pi with WLAN connection (for internet) and Ethernet. Both are working and I can connect to the Raspberry over both IPs.

What I would like to do is start vncserver (virtual-mode) and get an IP linked to `eth0`, but it automatically chooses `wlan0`.

Didn't find any documentation on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer: in file `/etc/vnc/get_primary_ip4` in paragraph `primary_ip_linux` replace line:

```
interf=`$awk '$2="000000" && .....`
```

with

```
interf=`$awk '$1="eth0" && .....`

if [-n "$inter"] then
  interf=`$awk '$2="000000" && .....`
fi
```

It works for me, but I'm not sure if there could be potential problems.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to do anything if you are using RealVNCServer on raspberry-pi. As `/etc/vnc/get_primary_ipv4` will automatically figure out all the "UP" interface. Interface "UP" means interface should have valid ip and if its ethernet interface then other end of ethernet wire should be connected to make link UP.

Below image shows 2 IP's (eth0 & wlan0) to access machine via VNC from.

[image: Image shows that there are 2 ip's(eth0 and wlan0) to access same machine via VNC]